# Is WSO2 still releasing under the Apache2 license?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

The WSO2 web site extols their participation in the open source community, and their github repository gives an option to download the Enterprise Integrator under the Apache2 license (I click the option of not getting automatic updates).  BUT, the following screen requires me to accept their evaluation/commercial license EULA to download the Windows installer!

Is this an oversight, or an indication of their strategic direction?

Comment: It's not uncommon for these kinds of projects to have an open-source license (i.e. you can get the source, build it yourself, ...) but binaries built by the creators are distributed under a commercial (often, but not always, free-as-in-money, but not free-as-in-beer) license. In other words: yes, you can use at as open source if you build it yourself (or find someplace that built it and distributes the binaries under the same license).

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the builds/releases with open source Apache2 license, are only on the github as ZIP files. For example: [WSO2EI 6.6.0](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases/tag/v6.6.0), and on the bottom site you will see assets: *wso2ei-6.6.0.zip*. This package is released under Apache2 license, and the license is included in that zip file.

The installation from wso2.com site, or installation from apt-get are considered as commercial license.

Comment: Would it be effective to evaluate the value you can get from their commercial offering by using the downloads available on github?  I have been through this with MuleSource which had the engine and some core parts available as open-source, but they had proprietary management and deployment tools that were integral to effective use of their product.

Comment: The main value of the commercial offering is that they give you 'WUM' - WSO2 Update Manager, to keep the produts up to date.  So it mostly depends on your requirements , especially the security. Because as you see, the open-source builds are old: (Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 - released on 20 Dec 2019, API Manager 3.2.0 - released on 25 Aug 2020).  The pricing for commercial, as I know are not cheap.. The other solution is build own CI/CD from source which are updated.
Personally, the direction they took is not very nice, but business is business.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!  I agree with your assessment on this direction.  It was very frustrating when MuleSource went this way.  It would be relieving if they made minor releases when they make substantial updates.